# get the value after a search string in python

Tags: python, string, split

I need to retrieve the values from logs that contain the lines in similar below format as
My input line looks like this:

```
line = "(last_bytes wrote 66560002, cur_bytes read 33280206, curr_bytes wrote 66560002, blks read 103335128)"
```

I need to get the value based on my search string

```
Ex: search(last_bytes wrote)  =  66560002
    search(cur_bytes read)  = 33280206
```

I had tried to split line and search for next string after wrote/read, but that does seem to return unexpected values.

Is there a way to get these values In python ?

Comment: Is there supposed to be a comma here: `curr_bytes wrote 66560002blks read 103335128`?

Comment: Yes, there is a comma...

Answer (score 5):

You can create a `dict` containing all the key-value pairs in the line, which is helpful for searching for multiple values in each line.

```py
lookup = dict(part.rsplit(' ', 1) for part in line[1:-1].split(', '))
# {'last_bytes wrote': '66560002', 'cur_bytes read': '33280206', 'curr_bytes wrote': '66560002', 'blks read': '103335128'}
print(lookup['last_bytes wrote']) # 66560002
```

Answer (score 1):

Using regex:

```
 re.findall(r'(?<=\blast_bytes wrote )\d+', line)
```

That will return a list containing any number that is following the string `last_byte wrote`

Comment: Brilliant answer. I get the output as desired with your suggestion. Thanks for the help!!

Comment: Those brackets mean that you are getting a list. You can get the first item from a list like `mylistobject[0]` in this case `re.findall(r'(?<=\blast_bytes wrote )\d+', line)[0]`, note that will fail with an error if `findall()` comes up empty.

Answer (score 0):

If in your line you always have text1_text2 text3 number then you can easily create a function using the split function.

If not it's more difficult, can you be more precise please?

Comment: It need not be always text1_text2 text 3 number. For instance line can have something like this "curdata 121034, pastdata 1245"

Comment: okay but do you always know what is the argument of the function ? so the looking is element is always the number which is in part write ? we can't have pasdata 123 45 ?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Another option using a regex with 2 capture groups, and then creating a dictionary.

The first group excludes matching a comma or parenthesis, the second group matches 1 or more digits.

```
([^\s,()][^,()]*?)\s+(\d+)
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/RPk4kJ/1) group matches.

Or if there should be "read" or "wrote" in it and preceding word characters:

```
(\w+ (?:read|wrote))\s+(\d+)
```

See another [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xhfFcG/1).

```
import re

pattern = r"([^\s,()][^,()]*?)\s+(\d+)"
line = "(last_bytes wrote 66560002, cur_bytes read 33280206, curr_bytes wrote 66560002, blks read 103335128)"
print(dict(re.findall(pattern, line)))
```

Both patterns will output:

```
{'last_bytes wrote': '66560002', 'cur_bytes read': '33280206', 'curr_bytes wrote': '66560002', 'blks read': '103335128'}
```